# how to properly open a modal within a modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using [bootstrap image gallery](https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/) to display my images, but what I'm doing is that the image gallery will be displayed inside a modal and once there you can click on the images to maximize them, my problem is that when I click on the image to maximize it, it uses the first modal as its view instead of it's own modal.

Modal Code:

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="viewModal({{ $data->id }})">View </a>


          <div id="myModal" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="max-width: 1300px;">
            <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div id="links">
                     <a href="image.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                    <img src="image.jpg" width="20%" alt="Banana">      
                    </div>
                     </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
            <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
            <div class="slides"></div>
            <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
            <h3 class="title"></h3>
            <a class="prev">‹</a>
            <a class="next">›</a>
            <a class="close">×</a>
            <a class="play-pause"></a>
            <ol class="indicator"></ol>
            <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body next"></div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                                Previous
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                                Next
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'll have to double check what I have at work, but I've just triggered another modal (technically outside of the current) and it pops up on top of the current instance. Is this what you are looking for? Your question sounds like you've got your image in the same modal.

Comment: i got my image inside modal 1, and when you click the image you see the bigger version in modal 2.

Comment: You should be able to get the same result with the modal positioned outside of the first.

Comment: @makingitwork - Your code seems to work fine for exactly what you want .  It opens modal1 within which I can see images and when I click each image it open another modal2 on top of it. (I placed an image inside `<div class="modal-body next"></div>` though just to replicate the image). It seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa it does open a new modal but instead of placing the new image inside modal2, it is placed inside modal1. it should be modal2

Comment: Ahhh.. then the problem is where the maximized `<img>` is generated. For me I manually added a `<img>` inside the `<div class="modal-body next"></div>` and it worked perfect. I'm sure in your case it's not generated inside it.

Comment: Can you check where does your maximized `<img>` gets loaded (I'm talking about your maximized image).

Comment: the placement is being done by bootstrap image gallery js. and it is placed there, though what i did now to make it work is that I placed modal2 inside modal1

Comment: *Bootstrap doesn’t support overlapping modals..* Please have a look here http://www.toptal.com/twitter-bootstrap/the-10-most-common-bootstrap-mistakes#showing-more-than-one-modal-prompt-at-the-time